# Replace frames in an AVI with Java

Tags: java, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm recording some screencasts and my crap recorder (Camtasia) recorded ~2000 videos with a brief black flash (2-3 frames) at, or near the beginning of each.

I'm looking for a way to automate the replacement of the black frames inside each video with FFmpeg, and I can currently detect which frames are black.

The problem I have is now: **How can I replace frame number X with the content of frame number X-1 in an AVI video**? Not looking to shorten the video, but just to replace a frame in-place.

Here's what I have so far:

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber g = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("res/video.avi");
g.start();

FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(new FileOutputStream(new File("res/video_out.avi")), g.getImageWidth(), g.getImageHeight(), 2);

recorder.setFormat("avi");
recorder.setPixelFormat(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
recorder.setFrameRate(30);
recorder.setVideoCodec(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
recorder.setVideoQuality(10);
recorder.setSampleFormat(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP);
recorder.setSampleRate(48000);
recorder.setAudioCodec(AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
recorder.setAudioQuality(10);

g.setFrameNumber(1);
recorder.setFrameNumber(2);
recorder.record(g.grab());

g.close();
recorder.close();
recorder.release();
```

And I'm getting a video back with empty frames (not even black), so I might be messing something here.

Anyone with experience with FFmpeg?

Comment: Do you need to do this in JavaCV? From what I can see, FFmpegFrameRecorder implements a limited API over libav* compared to the ffmpeg CLI tool.

Comment: Anyway, here's the method when using ffmpeg: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/23589/1871

Comment: This is super cool - it does remove the black frames, but the interpolation pixelates the entire resulting video, which ruins the quality. How can one set `ffmpeg` to keep exactly the frame previous to the blackness and replace them?

Comment: There shouldn't be any interpolation, only duplication. Share your full command.

Comment: `ffmpeg.exe -i input.avi blackframe,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=10:function=less -vsync cfr -c:a copy output.avi`

Comment: The pixelation is due to the default bitrate of 200 kbps. Add `-q:v 5`

Comment: Thanks, this improved the quality, however I notice the final video has 1-2 seconds trimmed from the end. I never looked at the whole video but now I noticed. How can I bring this back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174911/discussion-between-webuster-and-gyan).